# Java signed byte array compatibility with .Net Byte array

Tags: java, .net, arrays, jersey-2.0

We have an Java Rest service using jersey.

I receive integer data in form of byte array with CRC embedded into it. It's taken input as a Plain_text and variable is of type `string`.

We need to recheck the CRC values.

Since it comes from .Net application, in which all the values will be between 0 to 255 (signed byte array), and in Java it's between  -127 to 128 (signed byte array).

So I need suggestion for how shall I convert unsigned byte array into signed byte Array in Java?

Other problems what I'm facing are:

1. Whenever there is a value more than 127 then in java it will show a junk value or 63 (constant value not sure why).
2. I find it pretty strange that the values are less than 127, but CRC values are in other side.

I hope I have made my question clear and give suggestion.

Since its very large array anding (`& 0xFF`), would not make it. Since we have large array size.

Comment: How does the input look like? You say it's a string, is it a string of numbers from 0 to 255?

Comment: @POST
@Path("/{ID}")
 @Produces("text/plain;charset=utf-8")
 @Consumes("text/plain")
 public Response pullservice(@PathParam("ID") String deviceID, String data){ . data is the input parameter in method. but  what it takes intergers which are byte array encoded. Works fine. But need to add CRC check using SHA-256. Hence  compability problem between .net and java.

Answer (score 0):

To convert signed byte array to unsigned I used:

```
private static void printByteArrayFromSigned(byte[] arr) {

    if(arr == null || arr.length == 0){
        logger.debug("Array vuoto");
        return;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : arr)   {
        int x = b;
        if(x<0){
            x+=256;
            sb.append("["+x+"]* ");
        }else{
            sb.append("["+x+"] ");
        }
    }
    logger.debug(sb.toString());
}
//* converted
```

Viceversa from unsigned to signed byte array use:

```
private static void printByteArrayFromUnsigned(byte[] arr) {

    if(arr == null || arr.length == 0){
        logger.debug("Array vuoto");
        return;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : arr)   {
        int x = b;
        if(x>127){
            x-=256;
            sb.append("["+x+"]* ");
        }else{
            sb.append("["+x+"] ");
        }
    }
    logger.debug(sb.toString());
}

//* converted
```